# Permissioned Blockchain and Network Nodes

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, quorum, decentralized-applications

In a permissioned blockchain network, if you want to hide data specific to the individual parties of a trading relationship, then do the parties on both sides of that relationship have to be running their own node on the network?  Asked differently, is it possible for a private transaction between two parties to take place, where one or possibly neither of the parties run a node on the network?

Comment: Did you find what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, it depends on the blockchain, but it is possible in some cases.  The 'standard' blockchain, even permissioned, does not allow that as every node has a full copy of the ledger; however, the blockchain space is very large.

What you are looking for is Quorum, JP Morgans Blockchain. Quorum is a permissioned version of Ethereum that supports data privacy, specifically, it allows for transactions to remain private between the two sets of node groups(or parties) involved.  Check the link below.

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum

There are many other decentralized technologies that may be helpful as this space is still new but this blockchain network was designed specifically for this issue and is based on Ethereum which is one of the systems with more dev support.